# IBM COS Python SDK | Create client/resource object authenticated via HMAC keys

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

Using [IBM COS SDK](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python), is it possible to create a COS client/resource without specifying the field `ibm_api_key_id`, instead specifying some combination of `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` with other fields?
Tried the following without success:

```
get_cos_resource(region: str = 'us-east'):
    return ibm_boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        config=ibm_botocore.client.Config( 
            signature_version='oauth'),
        endpoint_url=f'https://s3.{region}.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud',
        ibm_service_instance_id=INSTANCE_ID)
s3 = get_cos_resource()
bucket = s3.Bucket("bucket-name")
print(list(bucket.objects.all()))
```

Returns:
`ibm_botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`.

Note - the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` are service credentials of the specified `ibm_service_instance_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all concerned, the following fix should work:

```
def get_cos_resource_hmac(region = "us-east"):
    return ibm_boto3.resource('s3',
                        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                        endpoint_url=f'https://s3.{region}.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'
                        )
```

Apparently the fields: `ibm_service_instance_id` and `config` can't be incorporated into the API request. The redundancy of `ibm_service_instance_id` makes sense, since unlike `ibm_api_key_id`, which is an account wide authentication key, the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` are bound to a specific storage instance.

**Note** - when authenticating using HMAC keys, remember to leave out the field `ibm_service_instance_id` when making write operations, such as `create_bucket()`, e.g.:

```
client.create_bucket(
                Bucket=bucket_name,
                CreateBucketConfiguration={
                    'LocationConstraint': f'{region}-smart'
                })
```